# Is it possible to print coloured output in kdb output?

Tags: kdb

I have a set of unit tests which I would like to run all at once and have a table with multiple rows where the ones with "PASSED" are green and the ones with "FAILED" are red.

I want the output to look something like this :
[image: desired output]

I know I have to use ANSI colour codes, but so far I wasn't able to make it work with `neg[1]` command or even using `system""`

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what do you mean by "making it work with `neg` or `system`". Neither of those have printing text as their primary function. You can use `-1` to print a string, and if that string contains an escape sequence, it will take effect.

```
-1"\033[31;1;4mHello\033[0m"
```

will print "Hello" in red with underline.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your shell supporting colour.
On linux/bash for strings you need to use `-1` to print to standard out.

```
// Colours for printing
G:"\033[1;32m" // Green
Y:"\033[1;33m" // Yellow
W:"\033[1;37m" // White
R:"\033[0;31m" //Red

// Add colour to text
o:{x,y,W}

-1 o[R] "FAILED"
-1 o[G] "PASSED"
```

kdb+ does not wrap symbols in `""` when displaying so they will natively show the colour

```
`$o'[(R;G);("FAILED";"PASSED")]
```

```
([] results:`$o'[(R;G);("FAILED";"PASSED")])
results
--------------------
FAILED
PASSED
```

[image: printing colours]

Answer (score 0):

Try this KDB '**Font**' library which I have written for text styling which supports text coloring and other features. It is based on ANSI codes which is not supported on all terminals. So check if that works for your use case.

https://github.com/asatirahul/quasar/wiki/Font:-Text-Styling-Utility-In-KDB

Example:
\ print error in red and bold

```
 q.font) print "Error: ", bold red "type"
```